# Flutter graphs plugin

Tags: flutter

For my app I would like to display a line graph (time x amount in dollars) where the user can:

1. Select a date on the graph to look at the amount of dollars at that date, as well as set a variable so more information about that date can be presented in another ListTile on the screen
2. View x-axis and y-axis headers. For example, I want to write "Dates" at the footer and "Balance in dollars" along the y-axis.
3. See a title for the graph

Is there a library for graphs that supports these features?

I've used bezier graphs but it doesn't support setting a variable when a user selects a date on the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Google already provides the graphs plugin visit here [charts_flutter 0.6.0](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter)

Google provides you the different type of graphs, also with the widget need to show `date`.